# Is it possible to create a list of variables that also have their own sublists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a item system for a program I'm coding and I'm simply wondering if this is possible. Currently I've been thinking of having a file with each variable in it and from there using this :

```py
ITEMNAME = [name,definition,etc,etc]
```

Currently I'm stuck at checking for a specific part of this item through a list.
Supposedly I wonder if I some how manage to figure out how I would pull the variable from the other list I could simply do this :

```py
# insert method of importing variables from another file above here
print(ITEMNAME(2))
```

And from there having it print it or do whatever I'd like to do with it. At the same time. If a variable is added to a list in the main file like so :

```py
LIST = (apples, oranges, the answer to the universe, ITEMNAME)
```

If it would be possible to go into list and pick out ITEMNAME and check for the definition of ITEMNAME.

Simply... There's alot I'm wondering about if it's even remotely possible to do most of these things. The code doesn't have to be simple. Just wondering if its a possibility.

Comment: Could you share what have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: use a dictionary of dictionaries?

Comment: @UdonN00dle I have tried what's in there and while it does work it doesn't work how id expect it to.

Comment: You're asking a few different things here: 1) how to access lists. 2) is it possible to have nested lists. 3) how to share global variables between files. 4) check for objects' types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, what you are looking for are dictionaries. They are like lists, but indexed by strings, so you can access item definition by its name. 
Here is an example:

```
>>> fruits = {'apple': ('tasty', 'red', 42), 'lemon': ('sour', 'yellow', 69) }
>>> fruits['strawberry'] = ('aromatic', 'red', 24)
fruits.items()
[('strawberry', ('aromatic', 'red', 24)), ('lemon', ('sour', 'yellow', 69)), ('apple', ('tasty', 'red', 42))]
>>> fruits.keys()
['strawberry', 'lemon', 'apple']
>>> fruits['apple']
('tasty', 'red', 42)
```

Both lists and dictionaries can be easily stored in data files in Json format -- see `json` module.

Comment: Now in the case that I wanted to pick out a specific part of what would be 'apple' like for example if I wanted to get red out of it... I've noticed that doing 'apple(0)' wouldn't work

Comment: Yes, the value of 'apple' is a tuple or list, then you can index them to get to a relevant part. But again, maybe some other data type would be better?
It can again be a dictionary or object, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can have list o lists in python if that's the question:

```
aList = [1,2,3]
anotherList = [5 ,aList,  6]
print(anotherList)

[5, [1, 2, 3], 6]
```

Comment: Well that is practically the question aside from the added part of whether i can grab something from the second list (or what would be your aList) from inside of anotherList. Which sounds a bit inefficent now. But mainly as long as its imported I can have it show up in another list as a name and not just the data that it contains?

Comment: @Randolph the name is the data that it contains, the reference in correct words... so, if you have the reference (in this case the variable name) you can access to the data. I don't know if I'm clear now, let me now :)

Answer (score 0):

use Bidimensional Array

```
name = ['John', 'Kyle', 'Rob']
age = [31, 18, 26]
city = ['NewYork', 'Lexington', 'Arlington']

people = [name, age, city]
```